# Using Ruby Webrick HTTPAuth with LDAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap, sinatra, webrick

The app I am writing has the ability to have a login popup appear and it authenticates against a hard coded username/password constant pair.  I would like to authenticate against our central LDAP server.  the we dont have a base however we do have a bind_dn string of "cn=USERFOO,ou=it,o=corporate".  The variables user/pass are passed in through the basic login box.

I am trying to do this through ActiveLdap however I dont mind using any other library as long as I can validate the credentials through a single sign on against our LDAP server using the HTTPAuth since is written completely in Webrick Ruby.  Below is a sample of the function I am calling.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
def authenticate_ldap(req,res)
    authlabel = "LDAP Authentication"
    HTTPAuth.basic_auth(req, res, authlabel) { |user, pass|
      ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection(
        :host => 'ldap.internalserver.com',
        :port => 389,
        :bind_dn => "cn=#{user},ou=it,o=corporate",
        :password_block => Proc.new { pass },
      )
    }
    return
end
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to what your actual question is.

Comment: Im basically trying to create a popup box that asks for a username and password that can authenticate against a central ldap server using HTTPAuth or some other non rails means.  I could use GET/POST with webrick however I am still having difficulty with using any library to authenticate against an LDAP server.  The question is what have other people used, and their syntax in order to accomplish this task.

Comment: What happens when you run the code above? Error message? Timeout..?

Comment: I figured out a solution.  The person who manages our LDAP server provided the incorrect ldap connection string, but even with that it still didnt work.  I am posting the solution that works below for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution.  The person who manages our LDAP server provided the incorrect ldap connection string, but even with that it still didn't work.

The solution I discovered that did indeed make a connection with very basic validation is something to this effect for anyone else interested in a very simple ldap authentication popup in pure Ruby.

```
def authenticate(req,res)
  authlabel = 'LDAP Authentication'
  HTTPAuth.basic_auth(req, res, authlabel) { |user, pass|
    if pass.to_s != ''
      ldap = Net::LDAP.new
      ldap.host = "ldap.serverfoo.com"
      ldap.port = 389
      result = ldap.bind_as(
          :base => "t=basetreefoo",
          :filter => "uid=#{user}",
          :password => pass
      )
      if result
        ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => "ldap.serverfoo.com",
                              :port => "389",
                              :auth => {
                                  :method => :simple,
                                  :username => "", 
                                  :password => "" 
                              }

        group_name = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("cn", "#{user}")
        group_type = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("groupmembership", "cn=infra,ou=IT,o=Corporate")
        filter = group_name & group_type
        treebase = "t=basetreefoo"
        ldap.search(:base => treebase, :filter => filter) do |entry|
          if entry.dn.to_s != ""
            puts 'success'
            return
          end
        end
      end
    end
    puts 'fail'
  }
end
```